# MySql can't create user

Tags: mysql, web-platform-installer

I'm logged in as root using the MySQL command line on windows.  This was installed with Microsoft Web Platform Installer. Version is

```
Server version: 5.1.72-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I can't create a new user with this statement

```
create user 'someuser'@'localhost' indentified by password 'somepassword';
```

or

```
create user 'someuser'@'localhost' indentified by 'somepassword';
```

I get this error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inden
tified by 'somepassword'' at line 1
```

Comment: Read the error statement carefully and that will solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo: `indentified` which should be `identified`